# Setting output of a program to pipe in Python 2.6.6

Tags: python

I was wondering how I would redirect the output of a program I would run with subprocess.Popen to the program I am using. For example, if I'm executing a script from Python ImageProcessing.py in.jpeg out.jpeg, I would like to instead do some extra processing in the higher level script; meaning that I would like the python code to replace out.jpeg with a pipe or some other sort of communication. (Also, yes I know it would be better to import in most cases, in this case I rather not).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` argument to `Popen`.  The stdout of the subprocess is a normal file. Example:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/cat", "hello.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in p.stdout:
    print("PIPE OUT [%s]" % line)
```

Comment: That would only work if it was going to stdout though? I'm not sure how to direct it to stdout from Popen. In this case, the program requires a file to write to.

Comment: So as far as I understood now: You have some program which writes to a file and there is no way to redirect this to stdout. Example: `myImageProcessor in.jpg out.jpg` and you want to post-process `out.jpg`? Two remarks: 1) Please re-word your question: the current wording is missleading. 2) Is the program able to use a PIPE as output? (E.g., it does not do any read-write access to the output or uses seek().)

Comment: It does look for write access; but I was hoping I could put in a pipe on the write? Sorry about the wording, will reword.

Comment: Many systems now provide `/dev/stdout` for programs that insist on writing to a filename.  If you can give `in.jpeg` and then `/dev/stdout` as the two pathnames, and that works, that might do the trick.  (Possible problems include: program insists on appending `.jpeg`; program insists on testing output file in various ways; etc.)